# linq multible join does not work in some empty tables

Tags: c#

hi I'm using 4 tables..

Sometimes it does not have information in the this tables(education or address or certificate)
so the results are coming empty..
If    have information how can I say?
example

```
**PersonTable**

PersonId    PersonName
 1453           george

**Certificate Table**

CertificateId PersonId  CertificateName  ( 0 records)


**Addres Table**

AddresId  PersonId    Adress
1           1453        ......
2           1453        .....
3           1453        ......
4           1453       ......
5           1453       ........

**EducationTable**

EducationId   PersonId   Education
1               1453          school name


**BankTable**

BankId       PersonId         Bank  ( 0 records )


Person table = 1 records
Certificates = 0 records
Address = 5 records
Education = 1 records
Bank = 0 records

var query = (from p in DbEntities.t_Person
                         join q in DbEntities.t_Address on p.PersonId equals q.addressId
                         join n in DbEntities.t_Education on p.PersonId equals n.EduId
                         join j in DbEntities.t_Certificate on p.PersonId equals j.CertificateId
                         join f in DbEntities.t_BankAccount on p.PersonId equals f.BankId
                         where p.PersonId.Equals(id)
                         select new { p, q, n, j, f }).FirstOrDefault();
```

return query values null ,

I do not see why these values​​?

```
Person table = 1 records 
Address = 5 records
Education = 1 records
```

I thought about it, but did not

```
var query = (from p in DbEntities.t_Person
                  where p.PersonId.equlas(id)
                  select p).singleOrDefault();

query = from p in dbEntities.Address
              WHERE P.AddressId.equlas(query.PersonId)
             select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing an INNER JOIN, which will only return records if all join conditions are met!  It looks like you want to do a LEFT JOIN, which will return all rows from the left table, and from the right table it will return any record that is found, and null otherwise.  [Here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is a good post explaining the different types of joins, with diagrams!

The Linq-to-Entities way to do a left join is `DefaultIfEmpty()`.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) for a usage example.

Comment: No problem!  Please mark as answer if this was the solution you were seeking.